# Meaning of "TypeError: string is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js

What does the error "TypeError: string is not a function" mean exactly?
Which conditions trigger the error?

A little context to show where the error appears.

The following program

```
"use strict;"
((console["log"])(42));
```

gives the error

```
/private/var/folders/k6/grq8nv093hj78x5m172d725m0000gn/T/tmp14388866091438886609658.js:2
((console["log"])(42));
^
TypeError: string is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/k6/grq8nv093hj78x5m172d725m0000gn/T/tmp14388866091438886609658.js:2:1)

    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

in Node. But `console["log"]` aka `console.log` ought to be a function.

However this program

```
"use strict;"
function displayln(v){return ((console["log"])(v));};
(displayln(42));
```

runs without any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it thinks you're trying to execute `"use strict;"` as a function. Try adding a semi colon after it

```
"use strict";
((console["log"])(42));
```